# Any way to speed up this pandas comparison?

Tags: python, performance, pandas

I have a [Python script](https://github.com/ewall/Hoolock-Gibbons/blob/master/importLogs.py) which is slurping up some odd log files and putting them into a pandas.DataFrame so I can do some stat analysis. Since the logs are a snapshot of processes at 5 minute intervals, when I read each file I am checking the new lines against the data entered from the last file to see if they are the same process from before (in which case I just update the time on the existing record). It works okay, but can be surprisingly slow when the individual logs get over 100,000 lines.

When I profile the performance, there are few stand-outs, but it does show a lot of time spent in this simple function, which is basically comparing a series against the rows carried-over from the previous log:

```
def carryover(s,df,ids):
    # see if pd.Series (s) matches any rows in pd.DataFrame (df) from the given indices (ids)
    for id in ids:
        r = df.iloc[id]
        if (r['a']==s['a'] and
            r['b']==s['b'] and
            r['c']==s['c'] and
            r['d']==s['d'] and
            r['e']==s['e'] and
            r['f']==s['f'] ):
            return id
    return None
```

I'd figure this is pretty efficient, since the `and`'s are short-circuiting and all... but is there maybe a better way?

Otherwise, are there other things I can do to help this run faster? The resulting DataFrame should fit in RAM just fine, but I don't know if there are things I should be setting to ensure caching, etc. are optimal. Thanks, all!

Answer (score 2):

It's quite slow to iterate and lookup like this (even though it will short-circuit), most likely the speed depends on how likely it is to hit s...

A more "numpy" way would be to do this calculation on the entire array:

```
equals_s = df.loc[ids, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']] == s.loc['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
row_equals_s = equals_s.all(axis=1)
```

Then the first index for which this is True is the `idxmax`:

```
row_equals_s.idxmax()
```

*If speed is crucial, and short-circuiting is important, then it could be an idea to [rewrite your function in cython](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas), where you can iterate **fast** over numpy arrays.*

Comment: Thanks, Andy -- I'm quite new to "the NumPy way of doing things" (guess I need to think more functionally!), so I'll definitely test out this idea. I'm even less familiar with cython and may look into that too. (I also realized there are some common Python optimizations I hadn't yet done in the rest of the code, too.)